# Pivoting python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Quick question:

I have the following situation (table):
[Imported data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjR7b.png)

Now what I would like to achieve is the following (or something in those lines, it does not have to be exactly that)

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9vKi.png)

I do not want the following columns so I drop them

```
data.drop(data.columns[[0,5,6]], axis=1,inplace=True)
```

What I assumed is that the following line of code could solve it, but I am missing something?

```
pivoted = data.pivot(index=["Intentional homicides and other crimes","Unnamed: 2"],columns='Unnamed: 3', values='Unnamed: 4')
```

produces

ValueError: Length of passed values is 3395, index implies 2

Difference to the 8 question is that I do not want any aggregation functions, just to leave values as is.

Data can be found at: [Data](https://www.kaggle.com/zikazika/crimes-un-datacsv)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: I suppose it is 8 question of the above, however I edited my question since it does not solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the method *pandas.DataFrame.pivot* is that it does not handle duplicate values in the index. One way to solve this is to use the function [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) instead.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Crimes_UN_data.csv', skiprows=[0], encoding='latin1')
cols = list(df.columns)
cols[1] = 'Region'
df.columns = cols
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Region', 'Year'], columns='Series', aggfunc=sum)
```

It should not sum anything, despite the *aggfunc* argument, but it was throwing *pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate* if the argument was not provided.